# DSAS asking to set metadata to proceed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, metadata, digital-shoreline-analysis-system

I'm using DSAS v4.3 with an ArcGIS software 10.3. Every time I edit the defaults and click to create transect I get the following error

[image]

Comment: Error messages should always be included in the Question body as text. This assures that the message is legible on all devices and can be searched for by others with the same problem. Note that 10.3 is now in a Retired support status, so you less likely to find others to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix by changing the metadata for the ArcGIS software to FGDC through customize > ArcMap Options > Metadata Tab